# jersey WadlAutoDiscoverable cast error due to apparent classpath conflict?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jersey, apache-kafka-connect

we have a Kafka Connect project where we rely on a [library](https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api) which fetches data from gitlab. This library depends on Jersey. Kafka also uses Jersey. When starting our connector, we receive a class cast error that appears to be caused by jersey having some kind of global discovery pattern that clashes when both `server` and `client` are in the same classpath.

```
org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlAutoDiscoverable cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
        at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.handle(AbstractApi.java:615)
        at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.get(AbstractApi.java:193)
        at poc.connector.gitlab.api.ExtendedIssuesApi.getIssues(GitlabExtendedApi.scala:34)
        at poc.connector.gitlab.GitLabSourceTask.poll(GitLabSourceTask.scala:49)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlAutoDiscoverable cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
        at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1295)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
        at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(CommonConfig.java:599)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(ClientConfig.java:403)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:450)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:419)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:319)
        at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.get(GitLabApiClient.java:382)
        at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.get(GitLabApiClient.java:370)
        at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.get(AbstractApi.java:191)
        ... 11 more


$ #inside of the plugin path of kafka connect:
$ find ./ | grep jersey | grep server                                                                                                                                                 Di 26 Feb 2019 15:46:41 CET
./schema-registry/jersey-server-2.27.jar
./confluent-kafka-mqtt/jersey-server-2.27.jar
./kafka/jersey-server-2.27.jar
./rest-utils/jersey-server-2.27.jar
```

How would we go about configuring our code to avoid the issue that somewhere in the process of our connect application, the wrong class is used? Or how do we avoid the cast error in the context of `AutoDiscoverable` implementations?

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue in one of our Kafka Connect connectors, which we solved by shading `org.glassfish` in our connector.

We package our connector as a "uber JAR" and place it in a path configured using the `plugin.path` setting.

See also [the Confluent docs for Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html) about this topic. There it is stated that

> ... a plugin should never contain any libraries that are provided by Kafka Connect's runtime.

We chose to shade instead, you might also be able to solve this by not packaging Jersey in your connector.

Answer (score 0):

I just add exactly the same issue. Developing a kafka source connector for gitlab using gitlab4j.

I fixed it by adding the following dependencies to exclude section of assemby and shade plugins:

```
<exclude>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</exclude>
<exclude>org.glassfish.jersey.core</exclude>
<exclude>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</exclude>
```